# Is this post really a duplicate?

Tags: discussion

[Smart phone factory reset, but forgot google account -- bricked now?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/139582/smart-phone-factory-reset-but-forgot-google-account-bricked-now)

The suggested answer is for 5.0 which has the option of wiping the data and doing a factory built in re-flash.  With 5.1 this isn't an option at all and you can't use the USB debugger or an otg usb.

Edit:  Ok I updated the post with more specific information about why the suggested solutions are not working for the xt1528 5.1.

Answer (score 4):

Answers don't determine whether *questions* are duplicates.

If an answer needs updating or another needs to be posted you should do one or all of:

- Leave a comment
- Upvote the question
- Offer a bounty
- Share the question

However, I'm pretty sure you're not correct about all of those changes since 5.0, since I was able to find and add methods that definitely work on some 5.1 and 6.0 devices.  Try it out.

You should also look at my second answer.  This is not supposed to be possible for you to bypass, especially not with a locked bootloader.  That's the entire point of the feature.

Comment: My question was specific to 5.1.  And it appears since 5.1 the solutions have changed as well.